# Galaxy S5 SM-G900F soft-bricked & stuck on Samsung logo screen

Tags: backup, samsung-galaxy-s-5

Hi may can someone to help here. Today i restart my phone don know why will stuck on SAMSUNG screen like the picture. I see a lot tutorial say have to factory reset. Is that anyway I can make backup now?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

You need to install stock Firmware into your mobile using Odin. You can find the Odin and Firmware for your Galaxy S5 from https://www.sammobile.com/firmwares/.
I don't think you can backup your mobile at this stage.

Comment: My data all will wipe if I stock firmware?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately, your data will be wiped and your mobile will be factory reset.